# Как сделать временной интервал загрузки файлов прелоадеров различных, стилей и js

Tags: javascript

Есть, например, файл `import.css`, а внутри — ссылки на различные прелоадеры и свои `css` стили:

````
    ```@import url('css/jquery-ui.min.css');
    @import url('css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css');
    @import url('css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css');
    @import url('css/Animate.css');
    @import url('css/bootstrap.min.css');
    @import url('css/bootstrap.min.css.map');
    @import url('css/bootstrap-grid.min.css');
    @import url('css/bootstrap-grid.min.css.map');
    @import url('css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css');
    @import url('css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map');
    @import url('css/1.css');
    @import url('css/2.css');```
````

и различные js файлы перед закрывающим телом body:

````
        ```<script src="js/jQuery 3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.map"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.jscroll.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js.map"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map"></script>
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>```
````

Как сделать временной интервал загрузки подобных файлов и отображение страницы после всех загрузок прелоадеров и стилей?

Хочется оптимизации процесса и чтоб не лезли все разом в узкое горлышко слабой связи интернета.

Comment: Используйте сборщик, чтобы собирался 1 файл

Comment: сборщик конечно можно сделать, но для новичка эт жестоко). ведь часто ненужное приходиться отключать и чтонить новое добавлять).

Comment: Ничего сложного в сборщиках нет, начните с gulp, за пару часов сделаете конфигурацию под себя, а потом просто копируете ее для каждого проекта

Answer (score -2):

в jQuery есть отличная функция:

```
$(document).ready(function{ здесь код })
```

код исполниться после полной загрузки страницы